# Why was Object.keys changed to coerce primitives into objects in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Does anyone know the reasoning behind the change from throwing an error when passing a primitive to `Object.keys` to silently coercing the primitive to an object and returning the result?

I'm not sure that anyone would expect `Object.keys('abc')` to return `[0, 1, 2]`, and it seems to violate the prime directive of "don't break the web". What if some website has code wrapping a call to `Object.keys` in a try/catch to handle callers mistakenly passing a primitive?

This is why I feel there must be a strong rationale behind the change. I would be very interested if anyone out there has some information about this.

Comment: Not an answer, but the [relevant section of the ES2015 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.keys) shows the first step as calling `ToObject` on the argument. The [earlier version](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) has its first step to check whether the argument is an object and to throw if not. To be fair, you are calling **Object**.keys, so for it to convert the argument to an object seems reasonable...but so does throwing an exception :).

Comment: As far as the answer goes, you *might* be able to find something by searching through the discussion archives at https://esdiscuss.org/.

Comment: Strings are iterable so they will return an index number as key, right?

Comment: So, I decided to dig, and there is a treasure trove of weird trivia there. [Apparently `Object.keys` was originally in Prototype.js and was ported over](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/object-keys-why-no-inherited-properties). Nothing about the change yet though...

Comment: interesting: many methods of Object were changed from throwing a type error on non objects in ES5 to doing something else in ES6: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additions-and-changes-that-introduce-incompatibilities-with-prior-editions (freeze, getOwnPropertyDescriptor, getOwnPropertyNames, getPrototypeOf, isExtensible, isFrozen, isSealed, keys, preventExtensions, and seal)

Comment: Expandos (numbered properties) are _own_ properties of Strings, so this makes sense.

Comment: @dandavis hmm that is an interesting point. Might be slightly counterintuitive but strings do have numbered keys in practical use. However, it still represents a breaking change in behavior from ES5, which is the main reason I'm surprised it was approved for ES2015. Usually any change to JavaScript goes through multiple rounds of ensuring it doesn't break existing code (much to the chagrin of many people).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any mention of this decision on esdiscuss, so I can only offer my own perspective.

As a commentor points out, this is part of larger trend in ES 2015 to allow non-object inputs more broadly. In the ES 2015 spec, the phrase, "In the previous edition, a non-object argument always causes a `TypeError` to be thrown," appears in reference to 10 different methods on `Object`.

For one, this change brings the behavior of `Object.keys` into congruity with the behavior of `for-in` loops, which have always been able to operate on primitives. Considering that the specification already required order to match between `Object.keys` and `for-in`, requiring the same set of valid operands seems unsurprising.

This change seems nearly as harmless as can be to existing code while greatly reducing the brittleness of `Object.keys`. Even in your case of a try-catch, it's difficult to imagine a case where successful `Object.keys` execution causes an actual problem. I can easily imagine code like this:

```
try {
    var keys = Object.keys(input);
} catch {
    // oops, input was a primitive; call `new [Constructor]` to wrap it
    var keys = Object.keys(
        new input.constructor(input)
    );
}
```

But this doesn't break when `Object.keys` doesn't error out; a successful `Object.keys` call makes the `catch` code obsolete.

Of course there might exist, somewhere, code like this:

```
try {
    var keys = Object.keys(input);
} catch {
    // oops, input was a primitive; that unlocks the secret prize
    giveUserAFreePuppy();
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to say, through a very silly example, is that the cases where skipping a `catch` block would be truly problematic for the operation of some code seem so far-fetched that breaking such code seems a small price to pay to get a less brittle `Object.keys` function.

Comment: You make a strong argument. Thank you.